# База данных Android

Tags: android, база-данных

Проблема при создании БД
Выдает ошибку, что не находит таблицу с таким именем
Можете подсказать где ошибка?

Код БД

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TASK";

    public static final String NAME_TABLE = "tasks";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TASK_NAME = "title";
    public static final String KEY_TASK_TEXT = "text";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + NAME_TABLE  +  "(" +  KEY_ID +  " integer primary key, " +  KEY_TASK_NAME + KEY_TASK_TEXT  + ")" );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Код в активити

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText editTaskTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_title);
    final EditText editTaskText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_title);
    Button buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add);

    final DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
    final SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String taskTitle = editTaskTitle.getText().toString();    //Получаю значения из макета
            String taskText = editTaskText.getText().toString();    //Получаю значения из макета


            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_TASK_NAME, taskTitle);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_TASK_TEXT, taskText);

            sqLiteDatabase.insert(DBHelper.NAME_TABLE, null, contentValues);
            //dbHelper.close();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.execSQL("create table " + NAME_TABLE  +  "(" +  KEY_ID +  " integer primary key, " +  KEY_TASK_NAME + " text, " + KEY_TASK_TEXT + " text )" );
```

Попробуйте данный код, скорее всего вы где то пропустили пробел из за этого БД не может быть создана, так же укажите типы данных создаваемых столбцов в таблице которые могут следующих типов:

NULL    Значение - значение NULL.

INTEGER Значение представляет собой целое число со знаком, сохраненное в 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 или 8 байтах в зависимости от величины значения.

REAL    Значение представляет собой значение с плавающей запятой, которое хранится как 8-байтовое число с плавающей точкой IEEE.

TEXT    Значение представляет собой текстовую строку, хранящуюся с использованием кодировки базы данных (UTF-8, UTF-16BE или UTF-16LE)

BLOB    Значение представляет собой блок данных, который хранится точно так же, как он был введен.

Так же поменяйте версию БД в параметре

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

У меня была подобная ошибка при создании новой базы в приложении, пока не сменил версию бд на более высокую. 
Это должно помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
public static final String NAME_TABLE = "tasks";
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TASK_NAME = "title";
public static final String KEY_TASK_TEXT = "text";

private static final String NAME_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "
        + NAME_TABLE + "("
        + KEY_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement , "
        + KEY_TASK_NAME
        + " text,  "
        + KEY_TASK_TEXT
        + " text );";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(NAME_TABLE_CREATE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема состояла в полях text, которые должны указываться при создании БД. Я дописал и все заработало. Всем спасибо)